# PyInstallerでエラー

Tags: python3, windows-10

現在、Windows10上でpythonスクリプトをexeにしようとしています。
そこで、PyInstallerを使ってスクリプトをexeにしようとしたら、次のエラーが出ました。

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

再帰的なアルゴリズムは使っておりません。
どうしたらよろしいでしょうか。
よろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 質問に記載されたエラーは実際のエラーの一部でしょうか。そうであれば、全体を載せた方がよいです。また、実行したコマンド、exeにしようとしているスクリプトもあった方がよいでしょう。もしスクリプトが長いのであれば、できるだけ削り、問題が再現する最小限のコードにして載せるとよいです。

Comment: python2.7でできましたので、クローズします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ishihara-flicfit さん、[Python 2.7 は 2020 年にはサポートが打ち切られる](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/)ため、可能であれば Python 3 系列にする方が良さそうです。また、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己解決した場合自分の質問に[自分で回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することができます。投稿してから少し待てば回答を承認することもできますので、よろしければお願いいたします :)